# Showing count of unread message

Tags: android

I am trying to emulate the unread message count shown on top right corner  of inbox.

Comment: can you please show me the code for Message Box you are written

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a `Notification`. [Here is some documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for `Notification`. The `number` field is probably what you mean by "increment", though note that `number` is not shown on all Android devices and therefore should not be relied upon.

If you have more **specific** questions, please feel free to open up a new StackOverflow question and ask!

Comment: @droid: The only thing that meets that description is the `number` field.